# бесконечное выполнение скрипта

Tags: php, websocket

доброго

изучаю socket'ы, серверный скрипт должен выполняться бесконечно ( в большинстве изученных примеров )

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

первое что пришло на ум, поставить этому скрипту цикл и при определенном кол-ве секунд редирект на себя. получилась бы перезагрузка

интересует теория. правильно ли делать бесконечное выполнение, или перезапуски тоже нужны?

Comment: При каждом перезапуске сокет будет рваться, что не есть хорошо

Comment: С циклом всё верно, редирект не делайте. В цикле не забудьте сделать проверку на "необходимость остановить работу" while (file_exists('./isCycleOn.txt')) { /*работаем до тех пор пока файл существует*/ } Так же не забудьте отключить вывод ошибок/предупреждений и им подобных вещей т.к. скрипт из-за переполнения буфера вывода(или как его назвать) выгрузится и скрипт придётся запускать заново.